# Query to show specific data from json array in postgres

Tags: jquery, arrays, postgresql

I have a json array in a column with datatype(text) `[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":2,"fd":3}, {"address":"127.0.0.1","family":2,"fd":5}]`

I want write a query so that it shows only the fd fields from the json array.How can I do this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select json_array_elements(your_column::json)->>'fd' from your_table;`. This will first cast your elements to a json and then unwraps the array and then select the the 'fd' field. If this doesn't work for you then enhance your question with exact details of the table and some sample data and expected output. This query may not be performant depending upon the size of the table. Also, it is better to store json data as `jsonb` data type in postgres from a performance standpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's working.Can you please tell me a way to join this resulted table with another column in another table.

Comment: Can you ask another question with full details of both the table structure? Give the details of how to create both the tables and sample data to insert and an intended output. This will help the community to give exact answer.
 With my current understanding of your database schema all I can say is that, use this query as a subquery in the other table.

Comment: I have two tablesA and tableB and have json struct data in column 1 of table A...and have json array data in column 1 of table B (both stored in text format datatype) ..now in that datas i want to extract specific fields from table A( json struct) and specific fields of (json array) from Table B and join them.